# Arc welder fail to download when first use

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I've just installed the "ARC Welder" app on chrome and tried to add APK. According to the description of the app, installing ARC Welder will automatically download and install ARC, a large one time download. But it just keep loading.

I'm using Chromium 76.0.3809.87 on Ubuntu 18.04. And I'm using a proxy server to access the Internet.

Chromium's console log repeats "[12666:12680:0813/130117.278747:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(219)] Closing stream with result -2"

On the proxy side, it shows that the app tried to connect "mtalk.google.com:5228" continously.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your same situation, tried both [ARChon](https://archon-runtime.github.io/) and [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) and experienced the behaviour you describe.

Unfortunately, it seems **ARC** (App Runtime for Chrome) **has been discontinued**, although I only found this mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Runtime_for_Chrome).